# Getting instance of a specific selector that is visible (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these elements and I want to get the position the elements that is visible or doesn't have the `hide` class. I know I can just loop through all these elements and count but is there a jQuery function that I can just target the specific element with less code?

```
<div class="panel hide">1</div>
<div class="panel">2</div>
<div class="panel hide">3</div>
<div class="panel hide">4</div>
<div class="panel hide">5</div>
```

Comment: $('div').not('.hide');

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke. Thanks for this but what I'm trying to get is the count (n) of the selector that doesn't have the class hide. I know I can get the instance by looping through all those divs but I just want a shorter code of there is such a function in jQuery.

Comment: Then its `$('div').not('.hide').length;`

Answer (score 2):

So you want the `div` element with the class `panel` but without the class `hide`?

```
$('div.panel:not(.hide)');
```

See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8A7H/)

---

To get the number of elements in any jQuery set you use the `length` property:

```
var n = $('div.panel:not(.hide)').length;
```

This stuff is all available in the jQuery API. Explore it and get into the habit of looking stuff up in it.

- [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector)
- [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector)
- [`length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length)

---

And to get the position of the element from among its siblings, you use `index`:

```
var index = $('div.panel:not(.hide)').index();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8A7H/2/)

This assumes that these are the only elements in their parent element. If they are not, you will need to check the index of the relevant element among the set:

```
var allPanels = $('div.panel'),
    notHidden = allPanels.not('.hide'),
    index = allPanels.index(notHidden);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8A7H/1/)

Note that these will still display `1` because `index` returns a 0-based index, i.e. the first element is `0`, the second is `1`, like in an array.

Comment: I want go get the instance. The count (n) of `.panel` that doesn't have the class `hide`.

Comment: I am very aware of those functions mate. What I am asking is the .eq(n) of that specific selector that doesn't have the class hide. With your suggested line, it throws up '1' (understandable) because it catches the selector. What I am after is the position (n).

Comment: @TarokKins If you were a little more clear in your question, I could have given you the answer (which is, funnily enough, also in the API). There's really no need to be quite so rude.

Comment: Which part of my comment thats shows me off as rude? Please do tell me.

Comment: @TarokKins I realise English isn't your first language, so perhaps it was unintentional. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I understand that this coughs out array-based indexes. Thanks again.